# How to add a parent entity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

My code-first data model started with the standard `ApplicationUser` entity, which included postal address and billing properties. Now I have extended my model by adding a parent `Account` entity:

- One Account has many ApplicationUsers; ApplicationUser now has a non-nullable foreign key to the related Account record
- Billing and postal address are now associated with the Account entity rather than the ApplicationUser entity, so the associated properties have been moved from the ApplicationUser entity to the Account entity

In order to update the database schema to incorporate the new parent table, I will assign each existing ApplicationUser to a newly created Account.  So, I need to do two things for each existing ApplicationUser:

1. I need to create a new Account row whose billing and postal address field values are taken from the ApplicationUser row.
2. I need to set the ApplicationUser.AccountId foreign key field to the primary key value of the newly created Account row.

Note that my code is hosted on Azure, and the data is in the Azure SQL Server.

The scaffolded Migration code looks like this (greatly simplified)

```
// Create the new Accounts table
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Accounts",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            BillingInfo = c.String(),
            PostalAddress = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

// Add the new FK column
AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "AccountId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "AccountId");

// Before we add the AspNetUsers.AccountId foreign key, we need to populate
// the Accounts table (one Account for each User)
Sql("some SQL command(s)")

// Make the column a foreign key
AddForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "AccountId", "dbo.Accounts", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);

// Deleted fields
DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "BillingInfo");
DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "PostalAddress");
```

As far as I can tell, my only option for creating or modifying data is to use the `Sql()` method (or `SqlFile()` or `SqlResource()`), as shown in the above code.

If I'm limited to using SQL, what sort of SQL command would accomplish the task?  Can I do it in one big ol' command with some sort of JOIN (to records that don't yet exist), or do I need to resort to SQL looping ([as shown in this article](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/kb/111401))?

Comment: List the relationship you're expecting in this format.... `1 account has many users`, `1 user has 1 account`... etc

Comment: You should create manual migration script using SQL for your specific rules, then create empty migration in EF using package manager console and insert this migration script there using `Sql(@"<your migration code>");` method

Comment: @raderick That's the gist of the question. I know I need something in the migration script where I added the "<do something here>" comment.  If I can figure out how to use something equivalent to the code I would use in a Seed method then I'd be home free because I could loop through the existing User records and create the associated Account records.  But if I'm limited to using SQL I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core idea is pretty simple:

1. Your schema and data migration should be in different migration classes
2. For migration you need to introduce temporary pseudo-FK column on the side that you are inserting, and migrate data using this column. High level idea looks approximately like this:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] ADD [_Temp_AspNetUserId] int;
> GO
>
> /*insert data into accounts with reference from AspNetUsers*/
> INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] (BillingInfo, PostalAddress, _Temp_AspNetUserId)
> SELECT user.BillingInfo, user.PostalAddress, user.Id 
> FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] user
>
> /*update original foreign key relationship for [AspNetUsers] table*/
> UPDATE [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
> SET AccountId = [dbo].[AspNetUsers].Id
> FROM [dbo].[Accounts]
> WHERE [dbo].[Accounts]._Temp_AspNetUserId = [dbo].[AspNetUsers].Id 
>
> /*drop temporary column*/
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] DROP COLUMN [_Temp_AspNetUserId];
> GO
> ```

Sorry for formatting, for some reason it looks a bit screwed up if I don't add comment tag.

Comment: Thanks a million for the SQL code. I understand how you are using the temporary column to match up Account rows with their associated AspNetUser rows. (I never would have figured that out on my own.) The part I don't get is "your schema and data migration should be in different migration classes".  Why can't I run this SQL in the migration class I showed in the original post, after the Accounts table has been added but before the FK is enforced?

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS you technically can, but I believe it's overall a good practice to split your schema changes and data migrations into separate migrations. I also remember some issues happening when applying schema migrations with data migrations together over the same tables, but not sure why they happened and I had to split them into 2 migrations.